# Error 406 when Drupal Services Session Authentication enabled (Drupal-iOS-SDK)

Tags: drupal, service

First, thank you to those of you who have put in a tremendous amount of work into building and developing Drupal-iOS-SDK.  It is an amazing piece of work and I am impressed by its power daily.

Second, as a bit of background, I am writing an iOS app that allows users to login to my Drupal site with their iPhone/iPad and access their inputted data currently stored/displayed in Views.

Now, to my question/problem.  So far, I have been able to successfully login to my Drupal site with the iOS app with OAuth and Session Authentication switched to off.  However, as soon as I enable  Session Authentication, I get a 406 error.  I have tried looking online for a solution but, unfortunately, I have been unable to do so.  What could be causing this problem and how would you recommend that I go about trying to resolve it?

On a similar note, my hypothesis is that disabling Session Authentication is what is causing me to get a 401 error when trying to get the app to display the views I've created.  Could that be the case?  Will resolving my issue above so that I can enable Session Authentication then allow me to access the views?

Thank you in advance for your help and have a great day!

Okay--I think I'm making some progress.

For the time being, I've disabled Session Authentication and don't have to deal with the 406 error. Additionally, I adjusted my Drupal views settings and now am no longer getting a 401 error when using DIOSView's viewGet. However, the responseObject for viewGet is a blank set that contains no view information. As a test, I implemented nodeGet that retrieves the node my view is linked to. I then ran the app and observed that the information returned in nodeGet's responseObject doesn't match the information for the user that successfully logged in. This makes me think that the session and/or user information is not getting passed from the app's first view (login view) to the app's second view (view that implements viewGet).

Can anybody help? I know the Drupal community, and Drupal-iOS-SDK community, is quite large and active. As such, I'm hopeful that someone can provide me with some insights and point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

Check the 'sessions' table in the database.  Remove any rows that have the 'uid' of the user you are logging in as and/or the 'hostname' (ip address) of the iDevice you are using to log in with.  I had the same issue, getting 406 when enabling session authentication in services using drupal-ios-sdk, and this is what resolved the problem for me.

The 401 "Unauthorized" status code is because the request requires authentication.  Once you get the session authentication working, check your roles and permissions.  Once you are authenticated, the user should be able to access the view if they have the correct roles/permissions.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  I haven't gotten a chance to try it out yet but will let you know if this works.

That being said, how often do you have to go in and delete those rows?  Put another way, do I delete them once and everything is good to go?

Answer (score -1):

I found this problem too.

Try following this method here. It works for me

https://github.com/workhabitinc/drupal-ios-sdk/issues/30

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  I haven't gotten a chance to try it out yet but will let you know if this works.